# How the current date is treated for a trailing/moving average

Tags: time-series, mean, moving-average

I'm not sure if this is more a stats question or a finance question, but I'll post it here. Let's say I have the following data for the sales of a product by day:

```
# date, sales
- 2014-01-01: $2.00
- 2014-02-02: $4.00
- 2014-02-03: $8.00
- 2014-02-04: $16.00
```

What would be the **2 day trailing average** on the following days:

- **`2014-01-01`** — How would this be treated because we only have one day's value at this time? Is this considered a `NULL` value or is the average still computed?
- **`2014-01-03`** — Is the two-day trailing average based on the dates `2014-01-03` (today) and `2014-01-02` (yesterday), or is it `2014-01-02` (yesterday) and `2014-01-01` (two days ago)?

Basically, how is the trailing average usually defined?

Comment: Up to you whether to include the present and whether to use whatever is available or to report a $k$-term moving average only if $k$ values are availabe. I wouldn't put any store in words here; I would want to see a formula or even better the code someone used. Sometimes only previous values are relevant.

Comment: @NickCox I see -- thanks for the feedback. How is this usually done in finance, such as nasdaq, nyse, etc. ? That is, when they say a "3 day moving average" does that usually include a current date?

Comment: Finance is not my specific field and I can't comment on practice there. It should be easy enough to uncover the rules used by looking at some data even if it is not documented.